# Client side validation not detecting a certain input == 0; why?

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to validate a form with some radio buttons and a range input with jquery (the page uses jquery mobile for the widgets).

Server-side, I'm seeing a few requests where price=0. I don't know how these are slipping through the client-side validation. Can anyone see any holes by which it would be possible to submit price=0? Are there any potential browser quirks that would allow a browser to bypass validation (apart from disabling javascript)? Unfortunately I don't have logging set up to be able to match browser user agents to the data. Here's a summarised version of the template:

```
<form>
    <p>First question:
        <input type="radio" name="taste" value="something">
        <input type="radio" name="taste" value="somethingelse">
    </p>
    <p>Last question:
        <input type="range" name="price" value="0">
    </p>
    <button type="submit" id="next" class="ui-btn">Next</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#next").click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if( $price.val() == 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length > 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("You forgot the last question!");
        } else if( $("#price").val() > 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length == 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("You forgot the first question!");
        } else if( $("#price").val() == 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length == 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("Please complete the form.");
        } else {
            $("#myform").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This question refers to jquery validation - what's on the server shouldn't matter.

Comment: Because you use radio buttons, you can use `$("[name=taste]").val() == null`instead of `$("[name=taste]:checked").length == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code :

```
    <form>
    <p>First question:
        <input type="radio" name="taste" value="something">
        <input type="radio" name="taste" value="somethingelse">
    </p>
    <p>Last question:
        <input type="range" id="price" name="price" value="0">
    </p>
    <button type="submit" id="next" class="ui-btn">Next</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    $("#next").click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if( $('#price').val() == 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length > 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("You forgot the last question!");
        } else if( $("#price").val() > 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length == 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("You forgot the first question!");
        } else if( $("#price").val() == 0 && $("[name=taste]:checked").length == 0 ){
            $("#error-messages").text("Please complete the form.");
        } else {
            $("#myform").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What changed? Explanation?

Comment: In IF condition what is $price?

Comment: Replace $price with get Value using price id.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that typo. Thanks.